# gganimate error with long-format data and plot_usmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to animate a map graph using `gganimate` but am running into the following error:

```
Error in seq.default(range[1], range[2], length.out = nframes) : 
'from' must be a finite number
```

It seems like this usually occurs when the variable used for `transition_time()` isn't numeric or the data's in the wrong form, but I don't know how that could be in my case; my data's in the proper long format and the variable for `transition_time()` is numeric and always finite.

Is this a specific issue with `plot_usmap()`? Am I missing something obvious?

My data is on [GitHub](https://github.com/burialrune/covid/blob/main/helpdata.Rda). Code below:

```
library("usmap")
library("ggplot2")
library("gganimate")

load("helpdata.Rda")

check = plot_usmap(data = df_map, values = "frac_cov") +
  scale_fill_stepsn(breaks=c(-100, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5,
                             0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 100),
                    colors=c("red", "gray100", "gray90", "gray80", "gray70", "gray60",
                             "gray50", "gray40", "gray30", "gray20", "gray10", "red"),
                    na.value="white") +
  labs(fill = "", title = "Fraction of excess deaths\nattributed to COVID-19") +
  theme(legend.position = "right", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  transition_time(month)

anim <- animate(check, nframes=9, fps=1)
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset has 50 unique fips values. The map data in the `usmap` package comes with 51. When `plot_usmap` creates the ggplot layers, it merged your dataset with the map data by fips code, which adds on NA values to the month column since one of the fips codes has no match.

(`transition_time` makes a fuss about this while `transition_state` doesn't. I'm not familiar enough with the gganimate package to theorize why that's the case.)

Add the following to your dataset before plotting. It should solve the problem:

```
df_map <- rbind(df_map,
                data.frame(month = sort(unique(df_map$month)),
                           frac_cov = 0,
                           fips = 11)) # the missing fips value
```

Result after running the same animation code shown in the question:

[image: map]

Comment: For posterity's sake--I also had to add `library("transformr")` to get the animation to run, and mine doesn't animate smoothly like Z.Lin's example--probably have to mess around with the transformr package to get that (?).

Comment: You may wish to check your gganimate package version. The more recent ones shouldn't require transformr to be loaded, and easing between transitions should also be linearly smooth by default.